# Orientation of Forge viewable generated in Inventor 2024 Design Automation not correct in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

We have an existing "Product configurator" site that has been working well with the 2022 Inventor Design Automation engine. We have recently enabled it to additionally work with the 2023 and 2024 engine versions. We are finding that with the 2024 version the orientation (home view) in the Viewer of the viewable does not match the orientation in Inventor.

This is what it looks like when using the 2022 and 2023 engines:
[image: Correct orientation]

and this is what it looks like using 2024:
[image: Incorrect orientation]

These are all using identical app bundles and Inventor datasets.

Is this a bug in 2024 perhaps, or is there something extra we need to be doing in this version?

Answer (score 0):

SVF files typically include information about what the "up" vector is for the included geometry:

[image]

The viewer makes sure to reorient loaded models to align their up vector with its own understanding of what "up" is.

Since you're building a configurator, are you perhaps using some custom placement transformation when placing the model into the viewer? If so, you may need to adjust the orientation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the behaviour now is that if there is **saved home view**, that will be used, otherwise the default view (**last saved state**) will be used.

So please check what the **Home** view is in your model.

Comment: Thanks @adam-nagy, there was a home view saved in the assembly, but just to make sure I have now opened it in Inventor 2024 and saved it. This has helped, the model is now displayed in the correct orientation, however it is now zoomed in way too far.
Also I've noticed that when orbiting it is a free orbit, whereas with 2022 and 2023 it is a constrained orbit keeping the ground plane level.

Comment: "zoomed in way too far" - that should be fixed in coming update
"free orbit" - all Inventor file translations on model derivative seems to have that. It's not clear if it was done on purpose or not

Comment: Does the switch to "free orbit" affect you in any way, or you were just curious why it happened?

Comment: It was just an inconsistent UX, plus in our situation a constrained orbit was more appropriate for the models concerned.
We ended up fixing both problems ourselves with some JavaScript code once the model has loaded.